# how to add shell environment variable to global env variable in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a below jenkins pipeline and it is working fine

```
pipeline {
  agent
        {
                node
                {
                        label 'test'
                }
        }

    environment{
        ansible_pass = 'credentials('ans-pass')'
        
    }

    stages {
        stage('Load Vars'){
            steps{
                script{
                    configFileProvider([configFile(fileId: "${ENV_CONFIG_ID}", targetLocation: "${ENV_CONFIG_FILE}")]) {
                        load "${ENV_CONFIG_FILE}"
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        stage('svc install') {
            steps {
            sshagent(["${SSH_KEY_ID}"])
 {
                        sh '''
                        ansible-playbook main.yaml -i hosts.yaml -b --vault-password-file $ansible_pass 
                        '''
                    }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now i want to pass the global environment variable id from shell instead of hartcoding
`ansible_pass = 'credentials('ans-pass')'`===>>>>
this ansible-pass1 should come from managed files(config provider)

I have already below from managed files

```
env.ARTI_TOKEN_ID='art-token'
env.PLAYBOOK_REPO='dep.stg'
env.SSH_KEY_ID = 'test_key'
```

Now how to add this credential id in this file?.Tried like below

```
env.ansible_pass = 'ansible-pass1'
```

and in jenkins pipeline refered the same as below

```
environment{
    ansible_pass = 'credentials($ansible_pass)'
    
}
```

But it didn't worked.Could you please advice

Answer (score 0):

As you are using secrets in config file it is better to use secret type 'secret file' in jenkins. Follow the [link](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-credentials/) to read about different types of credentials.

Also correct way of setting credentials is:

```
environment{
  ansible_pass = credentials('credentials-id-here')
}
```

Comment: Hi,I want to know,how to passenvironment variable for ('credentials-id-here')

Comment: you need to add credentials to jenkins, you can set creds id manually or it could be generated automatically.

Comment: I'm setting creds manually with specific id.but in pipeline that I'd I want to pass it as a variable since it will be different name for different pipelines and I don't want to hartcord that id